# SIFT Input to ANN

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, classification, sift

I'm trying to classify images using an Artificial Neural Network and the approach I want to try is:

1. Get feature descriptors (using SIFT for now)
2. Classify using a Neural Network

I'm using OpenCV3 and Python for this.

I'm relatively new to Machine Learning and I have the following question -

Each image that I analyse will have different number of 'keypoints' and hence different dimensions of the 2D 'descriptor' array. How do I decide the input for my ANN. For example for one sample image the descriptor shape is  (12211, 128) so do I flatten this array and use it as an input, in which case I have to worry about varying input sizes for each image, or do I compute something else for the input?

Comment: For ANNs you generally need inputs of a fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an exact solution but this worked for me. The main idea is as follows:

- Divide your image into a MxN grid.
- Obtain a set number of feature points for each sub-image.
- Concatenate the results for all the sub-images to obtain a feature vector for the entire image.

The supporting code roughly is given below (the function "pre_process_image"):

```
def tiles(arr, nrows, ncols):
    """
    If arr is a 2D array, the returned list contains nrowsXncols numpy arrays
    with each array preserving the "physical" layout of arr.

    When the array shape (rows, cols) are not divisible by (nrows, ncols) then
    some of the array dimensions can change according to numpy.array_split.

    """
    rows, cols, channel = arr.shape
    col_arr = np.array_split(range(cols), ncols)
    row_arr = np.array_split(range(rows), nrows)
    return [arr[r[0]: r[-1]+1, c[0]: c[-1]+1]
                     for r, c in product(row_arr, col_arr)]

def pre_process_images(data, dimensions=(28, 28)):
    images = data['image']
    features = []
    count = 1
    nrows = dimensions[0]
    ncols = dimensions[1]
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(1)
    for arr in images:
        image_feature = []
        cut_image = tiles(arr, nrows, ncols)
        for small_image in cut_image:
            (kps, descs) = sift.detectAndCompute(im, None)
            image_feature.append(descs.flatten())
        features.append(image_feature)
        print count
        count += 1

    data['sift_features'] = features
    return data
```

However this is **extremely** slow. I'm working on a way to optimally select features using PCA right now for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you apply Normalization on each image before getting the feature extractor.